# docker-java: access containers on docker host

Tags: java, docker, docker-java

I am creating docker containers inside my java application (using [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java)). I want to make the containers (all from the same image) accessible for the host.

Preferably all the containers listen on the same port, thus their IP address needs to change.

Note after I start the containers I connect them to a docker network (providing this information just in case).

Comment: There's [an example of publishing ports in the docker-java wiki](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/wiki#create-new-docker-container-and-start-it-with-exposed-ports).

Answer (score 0):

While I'm familiar with Java and Docker as well, I'm not familiar with "docker-java", so take what I say with a grain of salt.

I'd try and make use of the feature of docker networks that they act as a DNS servers for the containers connected to them.

What that means is that if you have a container called `docker_task` with a listener on port 8080, you can make a request to `docker_task:8080` and expect the network to resolve `docker_task` to the appropriate IP address.

Comment: This works inside the docker network but not outside the network. I try to access the container from the host.